# How to add custom files(.dll) based on 64 bit and 32 bit in clickonce custom file?

Tags: clickonce, .net-assembly

I have a problem in adding file reference for custom file in clickonce.

I want to publish my application based on web server via clickonce.From that URL, I need to download the files from clickonce based on 32 machine and 64 bit machine.

Because my application have separate dll files and they are all custom files. I added into custom file but how to mention to download separately based on 32 or 64 ?

Comment: Could you please add some code, so we can see what you already tried?

Comment: That's not possible, you'll need two URLs.  Since your app needs to be able to run on a 32-bit machine anyway, there is usually very little point in trying to support a 64-bit compatible build.